# Stop on hover moving text down

Tags: html, css

I have a list of icons and on hover, the size of the icon increases. However, the text below each icon moves down with the increase in size. How can is top this moving of the text?

HTML:

```
<div class="grid-wrap">
<div class="grid-col one-quarter">
  <span class="lnr lnr-mustache"></span>
  <p>Text 1</p>
</div>
<div class="grid-col one-quarter">
  <span class="lnr lnr-sun"></span>
  <p>Text 1</p>
</div>
<div class="grid-col one-quarter">
  <span class="lnr lnr-cog"></span>
  <p>Text 1</p>
</div>
<div class="grid-col one-quarter">
  <span class="lnr lnr-star"></span>
  <p>Text 1</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.grid-wrap {    
    margin-left: -3em; /* the same as your gutter */
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
}

.grid-col {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 3em; /* this is your gutter between columns */
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}

.one-quarter {
  width: 25%;
}

.lnr {
  font-size: 40px;
  transition: font-size 0.3s ease;
}

.lnr:hover {
  font-size: 60px;
}
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/UxuLvRPP1RURdXGBfpb7?p=preview

Note: the structure of the HTML should ideally not change as its important to maintain the text below the image for mobiles, tablets and desktops.

Comment: Perhaps use `transform:scale` rather than increase the font-size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `transform:scale` and `transform-origin`. You need some other minor changes too. So try this [**Plunk**](http://plnkr.co/edit/goPnBy95JaIs9OcGkO3z?p=preview)

Here's the snippets of CSS you need to change:

```
.lnr {
   font-size: 20pt;
   line-height: 1em;
   width: 1em;
   display: inline-block;
   margin-left: 10px;
   margin-right: 5px;
}

.lnr:hover {
   transform:scale(1.5);
   transform-origin:50% 50%;
   line-height: 1em;
   width: 1em;
   display: inline-block;
   margin-left: 10px;
   margin-right: 5px;
}
```

**Full code:**

```css
/* Styles go here */
.grid-wrap {
    margin-left: -3em; /* the same as your gutter */
    clear: both;
}
   
.grid-col {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 3em; /* this is your gutter between columns */
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.one-quarter {
  width: 25%;
}

.lnr {
    font-size: 20pt;
    line-height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.lnr:hover {
    transform:scale(1.5);
    transform-origin:50% 50%;
    line-height: 1em;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    width: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.linearicons.com/free/1.0.0/icon-font.min.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

  <div class="grid-wrap">
    <div class="grid-col one-quarter">
      <span class="lnr lnr-mustache"></span>
      <p>Text 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-col one-quarter">
      <span class="lnr lnr-sun"></span>
      <p>Text 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-col one-quarter">
      <span class="lnr lnr-cog"></span>
      <p>Text 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-col one-quarter">
      <span class="lnr lnr-star"></span>
      <p>Text 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

---

## UPDATE

To add animations, add the following to both `.lnr` and `.lnr:hover` in your CSS:

```
-webkit-transition: .2s ease;
-moz-transition: .2s ease;
-o-transition: .2s ease;
transition: .2 ease;
```

Here, you get a 0.2 second animation. You can also select another animation type if you want, such as `linear` for example. More info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)

[**Updated Plunk**](http://plnkr.co/edit/UrWXXhIkPBzp8qWCjoIu?p=preview)

Comment: this is great, thanks. However, i would like the fonts to GROW and SHRINK in size.. Rather and just change from big to small.

Comment: I see. Just add `transition: _s ease` to both your `.lnr` and `.lnr:hover` selectors, where "_" is the amount of seconds. See my update above.

Answer (score 1):

make a container with the maximum possible size of the element?

```
<div class='parent'>
    <div class='lnr lnr-cog'>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent{width:1.5em;height:1.5em;}
.parent .lnr{font-size:0.8em;}
.parent .lnr:hover{font-size:1em;}
```

That should work nicely.